# contour detection opencv

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I want to sort the squares of a 2D grid in a realtime video [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoIODoNcW5Q)

I have done that for an image using the following approach:

1. Find and draw contours
2. sorting the contours

   ```
   mask2 = np.full(gray.shape, 255, np.uint8)
   if lines is not None:
         for line in lines:
               x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
               cv2.line(mask2, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 0), 3 ,cv2.LINE_AA)

   cnts = cv2.findContours(mask2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
   cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
   (cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="top-to-bottom")
    cube_rows = []
    row = []
    for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts, 1):
          row.append(c)
          if i % 3 == 0:  
                  (cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(row, method="left-to-right")
                   cube_rows.append(cnts)
                   row = []

    number = 0
    for row in cube_rows:
           for c in row:
                   x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                   cv2.rectangle(mask2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0,0,0), 2)
                   cv2.putText(mask2, "#{}".format(number + 1), (x,y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0,0,0), 2)
                   number += 1
   ```

Comment: What is the question? You say you have done that already.

Comment: I said i have done that for an image, Now I want that for a real time video